# Why does Google Apps Scripts not update number of sheets in a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Apps Script that makes a spreadsheet, makes a bunch of forms, and links those forms to that spreadsheet. The next thing I want to do is tinker with the spreadsheet, rearranging sheets, changing names of sheets, etc. My problem is that my spreadsheet seems to not update to acknowledge the new sheets from the forms until after the entire script finishes.

Here's my code:

```
function mwe() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("Spreadsheet");
  var form1 = FormApp.create("Form 1");
  var form2 = FormApp.create("Form 2");
  Logger.log(ss.getNumSheets());
  form1.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
  Logger.log(ss.getNumSheets());
  form2.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
  Logger.log(ss.getNumSheets());
}
```

Here's my output:

```
Info    1.0
Info    1.0
Info    1.0
```

If I log the id of the spreadsheet, I can make a new script:

```
function mwe2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[redacted]");
  Logger.log(ss.getNumSheets());
}
```

This has the expected output:

```
Info    3.0
```

Does anyone know why this is? I've tried storing the id, reopening the spreadsheet with that id, and logging the number of sheets in that variable, but I always get the same thing unless I run a new script.

Comment: Not sure but try using SpreadsheetApp.flush()

Comment: Reading the documentation for `flush()` gives a good reason for why that fixed it: pending changes don't apply immediately, as doing them in batches can help with performance. If you want to write that up as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Cooper good one ! I thought this was used only if you made changes on the sheet itself. Didn't know that it works that way as well.

Comment: I didn't either I was just guessing.  But I knew if I was wrong I find out it pretty quickly.  It's what I would have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Cooper suggested, [`SpreadsheetApp.flush()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) solved the issue:

```
function mwe() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("Spreadsheet");
  var form1 = FormApp.create("Form 1");
  var form2 = FormApp.create("Form 2");
  Logger.log(ss.getNumSheets());
  form1.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Logger.log(ss.getNumSheets());
  form2.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Logger.log(ss.getNumSheets());  
}
```

Comment: You need to flush after you set the destination for the form. I just ran this code, and it output 1.0 all three times.

Comment: @PiFisher I updated my answer. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: Yep, that works now (after fixing the missing `r` in `SpreadsheetApp`).